# What areas of math are related to both $\pi$ and $\varphi$?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, knowledge

What areas of math are related to both $\pi$ and $\varphi$?

There are at least two answers.

Comment: In this question,is $\varphi$ the golden ratio?

Comment: @Roby5 Maybe, or maybe not. Adding the lateral thinking tag may be a give away, but it is fair.

Comment: "There are at least two answers." - How is this question not too broad?

Comment: @Bob I'm shaking my head at you.

Comment: @question_asker I bite my thumb at you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to puzzling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Number theory,

because

> in number theory, $\pi(n)$ denotes the prime-counting function (the number of primes $\le n$), and $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler totient function (the number of integers between $1$ and $n-1$ that are relatively prime to $n$).

Comment: This was the intended explanation for Number Theory.

Answer (score 5):

I hope I'm missing the point, but I'll just answer this like it was a normal question:

> Geometry and Number Theory

Because

> Pi and the Golden Ratio show up in both Geometry and Number Theory.  Though I feel like if this is a valid answer, there are dozens of other valid answers

Comment: This were the two things I had in mind, but I don't think that Pi and the Golden Ratio are very common in Number Theory. However, there are other reasons why it is related to Number Theory, for which I refer to the answer by Big Black Box.

Comment: Ok, but I'll make a couple comments:  1)This isn't really a puzzle.  2)The greek letters pi and phi are used in basically every branch of mathematics and physics with various meanings.  I was really hoping the real answer would be a joke or a pun of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

The **area** of a circle with radius $\phi$ is $\pi \phi^2$, which is very obviously related to both numbers.

Answer (score 3):

> In algebra (specfically polynomials) , the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial is defined as $$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\stackrel{1\leq k \leq n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}} \left(x-e^{2i\pi\frac{k}{n}}\right)$$

Also,

> In probability theory, the probability density function of the normal distribution. $$\phi(x) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}\cdot e^{-x^2/2}$$

Please see that $\varphi$ is the same as $ϕ$ for both the above mentioned functions.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?

Answer (score 2):

Are they both

> Transcendental

numbers?

Comment: Assuming you take $\varphi$ to be the golden ratio, it is not transcedental number, since $\varphi^2-\varphi-1=0$. They are both irrational though. Also, your answer is not really an *area* of math.

Comment: Hm. Then I'm out, but I'll leave it up. Unless of course the answer is a man.